# РНР загружает все подключаемые файлы, или только те, которые будут выполнены?

Tags: php

Предположим есть условие

```
if (условие) {
    require_once 'raz.php';
} else {
    require_once 'dva.php';
}
```

Подключаться будут оба файла? Или только тот, что соответствует условию? Запрашивает ли PHP файл, который не нужен по условию? Видит ли он его как

```
if (условие) {
    echo 'Первый';
} else {
    echo 'Второй';
}
```

или как

```
if (условие) {
    echo 'Первый';
} else {
    require_once 'dva.php';
}
```

Когда содержимое raz.php:

```
echo 'Первый';
```

dva.php:

```
echo 'Второй';
```

Comment: Почему вы сами не вставите 1 раз и не посмотрите что и как вызывается, и это займет 2 минуты.

Comment: А как проверить? Я вижу только итог: 'Первый'. Подгружается ли второй файл не вижу. Вероятно, что можно проверить, если сравнивать скорость обработки файла. Вопрос написала, так как возможно подобные опыты уже кто-то проводил или где-то в php.net прописано поведение.

Comment: Если файл загрузится, он обработается и выведет результат. Если он ничего не вывел, значит не загрузился.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насчет померить разницу в скорости загрузки - это, конечно, идея *очень* так себе.

Но проверить все равно можно, причем сильно проще

```
if (false) 
    require 'non_existent_file';
}
echo "Не грузит";
```

Comment: Действительно сильно проще :)

Answer (score 2):

Будет выполняться условие. Файлы не подгрузятся, если не выполнится условие.